# Maven - separate integration tests from unit tests

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing, profile

Is it possible to isolate integration tests from unit tests within same module?

I created simple pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>prj</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/integration/**/*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>integration</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/integration/**/*.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

however with **mvn -Pintegration test** it doesn't invoke anything. If I comment out **excludes** section in main build - then it starts to execute tests, but without profile as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

instead of:

```
<exclude>*/integration/**/*.java</exclude>
```

try:

```
 <include>*/unit/**.java</include>
```

then in the integration profile do

```
<includes>
   <exclude>**/unit/**/*.java</exclude>
   <include>**/integration/**/*.java</include>
</includes>
```

you may have to play with getting the includes/excludes exactly right, but that's the general idea.

Comment: yeah, that worked. Seems like if you specify excludes pattern - you can not override it in profiles with includes.

Comment: the overrides in maven work exclusively on the syntactic level meaning you can only override like elements

Comment: Your suggesstion , it doesn't work right for plugin 2.19.1.