# How do I specify different class name patterns to be tested?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing

I'm coming back to Java world again...

I'm following a tutorial (https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) and when I run the tests using `mvn test`, none of the tests in `HelloControllerIT` are getting run.  It seems that only classes that end with 'Test' are considered.  I'm sure there is a way to add additional patterns so that `HelloControllerIT` is included.

Where can I find more information on this topic?

*This seems like a simple thing, so I'm probably not using the right keywords in my search (e.g., 'java spring boot test pattern').*

**Update**

Thanks to Yug Singh's answer, I was able to come up with a solution that I feel good with.  I added this to my `pom.xml` file and now I can run unit tests separate from integration tests.

I forgot about profiles...

```
+    <profiles>
+        <profile>
+            <id>integration</id>
+            <build>
+                <plugins>
+                    <plugin>
+                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
+                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
+                        <configuration>
+                            <includes>
+                                <include>**/*IT.java</include>
+                            </includes>
+                        </configuration>
+                    </plugin>
+                </plugins>
+            </build>
+        </profile>
+    </profiles>
```

Run unit tests

```
mvn test
```

Run integration tests

```
mvn test -Pintegration
```

References (StackOverflow):

- [Maven - separate integration tests from unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185936/maven-separate-integration-tests-from-unit-tests)
- [Maven: How do I activate a profile from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927064/maven-how-do-i-activate-a-profile-from-command-line)

Comment: See https://github.com/dcvezzani/hello-spring to see the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out the following in pom.xml file:

```
<build>
  <testSourceDirectory>src/main/java</testSourceDirectory>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.16</version>
       <configuration>
          <includes>
             <include>**/*.java</include>
          </includes>
       </configuration>
    </plugin>
 </plugins>
```

IMHO, you should place the tests in test packages only as that is the convention.